# PHP Switch with 2 values

Tags: php, compare, switch-statement

is there a way to the php's `SWITCH` but with 2 values? Here's what I'm looking for

```
switch(a, b){
    case 1,2: some code... ; break;
    case 3,4: some code... ; break;
    case 3,6: some code... ; break;
    case 5,2: some code... ; break;
    case 1,3: some code... ; break;
    case 8,5: some code... ; break;
}
```

I know this won't work, so how would i do something along these lines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use an array with 2 elements since `==` comparison checks the array values:

```
$a = 3;
$b = 6;

switch([$a, $b]){
    case [1, 2]: echo '1'; break;
    case [3, 4]: echo '2'; break;
    case [3, 6]: echo '3'; break;
    case [5, 2]: echo '4'; break;
    case [1, 3]: echo '5'; break;
    case [8, 5]: echo '6'; break;
}
```

Outputs `3`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some string instead if it isn't heavy processing:

```
$variable= "1,2";

switch($variable){
    case "1,2": some code... ; break;
    case "3,4": some code... ; break;
    case "3,6": some code... ; break;
    case "5,2": some code... ; break;
    case "1,3": some code... ; break;
    case "8,5": some code... ; break;
}
```

Comment: @wes: Yes I find PaulPRO's answer more accurate. Mine was just another possibility I shared :)

Comment: This wasn't the best solution, however it would work. So upvote from me.